# Register IModel and ILogger in Startup.cs with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, rabbitmq, simple-injector

I'm building a Worker Service who is a separated project from my main Web project. This Worker Service is responsible for consume RabbitMQ messages and send this message to MailSender. But, I'm not realizing how to register what I need as Dependency Injection. I figure out how to include these services in IoC, doing this:

```cs
// Create RabbitMQ connection to send as DI
container.Register<IModel>(() => CreateChannel(container), Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Register<EmailConfig>(() => ConfigureMail(container), Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Register<IEmailSender, EmailSender>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

The problem is that my Worker.cs have to receive `ILogger<Worker>, EmailSender emailSender, IModel channel` as DI and I figure out how to register my Email configurations, but I can't reach how to register these ILogger and IModel. So, my ConfigureServices from Startup.cs is like that:

```cs
var mailConfig = Configuration.GetSection("SMTP").Get<EmailConfig>();
services.AddSingleton(mailConfig );

var rabbitConfig = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQ").Get<RabbitMQConfig>();
services.AddSingleton(rabbitConfig);

services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
```

IModel is from RabbitMQ (AMQP Model)

Comment: What is `IModel` in this case?

Comment: If you're using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` then use MEL's DI registration method rather than registering it yourself.

Comment: @Dai IModel is from RabbitMQ.Client (AMQP Model)

Comment: To register **open** generic types like `ILogger<T>`, use `typeof(ILogger<>)` (yes, that's valid C#). Like so: `container.Register( typeof(ILogger<>), () => loggerFactory.CreateLogger( etc ) )` (but I've forgotten what to put for `etc`...)

Comment: I'm trying to do this to my WorkerService and I think the reference is not found `(container.Register(typeof(ILogger<Worker>)`

Comment: `ILogger<Worker>` is a **closed** generic type, you need to use `typeof()` with an **open** generic type: `typeof(ILogger<>)`, don't use `typeof(ILogger<Worker>)`. That's not a reference error.

Comment: This gives me: `'The given type ILogger<TCategoryName> is not a concrete type. Please use one of the other overloads to register this type.
Arg_ParamName_Name'`

Comment: That error message has the information you need - are you having problems understanding it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213207/discussion-between-isac-moura-and-dai).